# Chrome extension - debugging "aww Something went wrong" error

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a Chrome extension to automate some stuff on the browser, it's going nicely, but after several hours I get the "aww something went wrong on the pages display" error (or whatever this error is in English) which is basically my tab crashing.

The problem is that I have no idea of what it is causing this and, as it comes after hours (been running fine for 15 hours today) it's extremely hard to debug.

#### So my question is: Is there a way I could get an idea of what is causing that? or at least get some 'logs' of what's going on?

Background:

- This extension is to automate stuff: a lot of DOM interactions, rarely fetching some APIs.
- I run it in incognito mode.
- Chrome version: 73.0.3683.103
- OS: Ubuntu 18.x
- It has been running perfectly fine the last week while I was working on it, just 3 days ago it started happening

Comment: Check out: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker Thanks for your response i'm gonna look it up